# Need help interpreting crash .dmp file

Tags: windows, drivers, bsod

My computer crashed during a game of League of Legends. I rebooted and activated Verifier.exe to check all my drivers upon restart. On rebooting I got another BSOD with error message DRIVER_VERIFIER_IOMANAGER_VIOLATION. I tried force restarting a couple times, but the automatic repair was not working. So I restored the computer to a previous point and now it's up.

I looked in the .dmp file for the crash and I'm not sure what to do about the drivers that were highlighted as a part of the error stack.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Joseph Quinsey, thank you for suggesting an edit. As a new user I was unable to add the photos myself.

Comment: you must zip and upload the folder C:\Widows\Minidump, otherwise we can't help you. It may be caused by the keyboard driver.

Comment: I'm not sure how to add a file, so here's a link to the file. (it's zipped)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/fa2gpi7nv9nhm2d/121713-28890-01.zip

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is caused by the keyboard driver [InputFilter_FlexDef2b.sys](http://www.sysnative.com/drivers/driver.php?id=InputFilter_FlexDef2b.sys). Download and install a newer version.

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_VERIFIER_IOMANAGER_VIOLATION (c9)
The IO manager has caught a misbehaving driver.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000006, IRP passed to IoCompleteRequest contains invalid status
Arg2: 0000000000000103, the status
Arg3: ffffcf8007e1a900, the IRP
Arg4: 0000000000000000

Debugging Details:
------------------


BUGCHECK_STR:  0xc9_6

DRIVER_VERIFIER_IO_VIOLATION_TYPE:  6

IRP_ADDRESS: ffffcf8007e1a900

DEVICE_OBJECT: ffffe00005193260

DRIVER_OBJECT: ffffe0000546a490

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  VERIFIER_ENABLED_VISTA_MINIDUMP

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.16384 (debuggers(dbg).130821-1623) amd64fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff8021a4eca5b to fffff80219fd9ca0

STACK_TEXT:  
nt!KeBugCheckEx
nt!IovCompleteRequest
InputFilter_FlexDef2b
0x0
0x0
0x0



IMAGE_NAME:  InputFilter_FlexDef2b.sys

BUCKET_ID:  0xc9_6_VRF_InputFilter_FlexDef2b+1c30

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0xc9_6_vrf_inputfilter_flexdef2b+1c30


Loaded symbol image file: InputFilter_FlexDef2b.sys
Image path: \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\InputFilter_FlexDef2b.sys
Image name: InputFilter_FlexDef2b.sys
Timestamp:        Sat Jun 19 02:36:01 2010
```